# How can I use regular expressions to find an entire log line using a regex from the log message only?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have many apache logs where the message is similar to this:

GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 500 21471

I have many of these logs stored in ElasticSearch, and I would like to retrieve them by using a regular expression. For example, the "GET editor/103HTTP/1.1" and "21471" can vary, so I set them as wildcards. I would like to obtain the apache logs where the message **GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 500 21471** exists by searching with the pattern *** 500 ***, where * represents the wildcard. How can I achieve this using regular expressions? Different logs have different messages, so the number of wildcards can very as well.

P.S: I already know how to set up a regexp query in ES.

Comment: If you just want a regex to get 500, then you can use: `.*\b500\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/bG3tH8/2)

```
^GET ((?!500).)*\b500\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/g8Kt-sVDDZuELiMx)

Answer (score 0):

here you go

**Regex**

```
/(.*500.*)/g
```

**Test String**

```
GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 500 21471
GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 200 21471
GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 500 21471
GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 220 21471
GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 500 21471
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - 1. [0-32]  `GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 500 21471`
- MATCH 2

  - 1. [66-98] `GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 500 21471`
- MATCH 3

  - 1. [132-164]   `GET editor/103HTTP/1.1 500 21471`

**Demo**

try [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/aW7zC3/1)